# wait for a promise to finish and then execute the next one

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to execute the deletion of some files in the file system and then complete the deletion in the ddbb.

I'm trying to execute first the deletion in the file system because I need to  make a consult to the ddbb and afterwards, delete from the ddbb.

I'm trying to execute it as follows:

```
public deleteApplicationInFileSystem = (request: any): Promise < void > => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.registryService.deleteApplicationInFileSystem(param1, param2, param3).then(() => {
      resolve();
    }).catch((err: any) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  })
}
```

and then I'm calling this method inside deleteApploicationFromDDBB as follows:

```
public deleteApplication = (request: any, response: Response): void => {
  this.deleteApplicationInFileSystem(request).then(() => { //
    this.registryService.deleteApplicationVersionInDDBB(parm1, param2, param3).then(() => {
      response.status(200).json({
        response: "Done."
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      if (err.split(",")[0] === "fieldNotFoundError") {
        response.status(404).json({
          response: {
            errorMessage: 'error 1'
          }
        });
      } else {
        response.status(400).json({
          response: {
            errorMessage: 'error 2'
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    if (err) {
      response.status(400).json({
        response: 'Error deleting applicaion from the file system'
      });

    }
  })
}
```

I have tried to write an async-await function, but it doesn't work. I'm quite new with Node, and any help to solve this would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Your code, while not elegant (avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern), doesn't look unreasonable, what problems are you having with it?

Comment: `this.registryService.deleteApplicationInFileSystem` - this already returns a promise, so no need to wrap it in a promise constructor and you have unnecessarily nested `then()` method calls within `then()` method callback functions. You could just chain them sequentially instead of nesting them

Comment: the problem is that it seems that it's returning always a 400 as it seems to have deleted the document in the ddbb so, deletion in the file system always fails.

Answer (score -1):

With async / await you could right it like this:

```
public async deleteApplicationInFileSystem (request: any): Promise < void > {
  // This method must return Promise as well for this to work
  return this.registryService.deleteApplicationInFileSystem(param1, param2, param3);
}
```

```
public async deleteApplication (request: any, response: Response): Promise < void > {
  try {
    await this.deleteApplicationInFileSystem(request);
    await this.registryService.deleteApplicationVersionInDDBB(param1, param2, param3);
    response.status(200).json({ ... });
  } catch(error) {
     // Handle error
  }
)
```